# Grub not showing after installation

Tags: grub2

I have formatted my machine with ubuntu covering the full drive.

Now i want to install windows xp on it( dont want to keep ubuntu on it as the user was not computer savvy).

The bootable disk is not showing in the screen.

I believe we have to change some setting in the grub loader of ubuntu - but not sure about this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Mady - your question is very difficult to understand - I've assumed that my update is what you were intending.  Please adjust and expand your question - please explain exactly what you are seeing on the screen - take a screenshot with a camera phone and link it here.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to boot frem the Win XP CDRom and format you Disk with the NTFS Filesystem during the XP INstallation process. Do I missunderstand your question? Please give more information of what you have done yet.